# Get a File from Activity to use in Daydream

Tags: java, android, android-activity, daydream

I'm developing an App that must use a video to set the screensaver on the phone, actually I can select the video on the app but I cannot pass that value (File or the path) to use it in the DayDream. Every time that the screensaver tries to run it crashes, in the logcat it appears as: null

Any way to get that value from my app to use it in the daydream service that runs in the ScreenSaver? (if I write the file path manually on the code it plays the video with no problem, but I must be able to set up the video from the App)

Regards

EDIT: In the Dreamservice class I use this to play the video, as I said when I use the path directly (you can see it in the code as heman.mp4) it works but I need to pass the File/Path from the app

```
private void reproducirVideo()
{
    // Se crean los controles multimedia.
    reprod2.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    //System.console().printf("EL PATH DEL VIDEO!!!!! : " + video1Path);
    //reprod2.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("/sdcard/heman.mp4"));
    System.out.println("PATH DEL VIDEO: " + Linker.GetPath1());
    //reprod2.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(Linker.GetPath1()));

    //reprod2.setVideoURI(FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "com.toolkit.app.screensaver02.provider", getFileStreamPath("/sdcard/heman.mp4")));
    reprod2.setVideoURI(Uri.fromFile(Linker.GetPath1()));
    //reprod2.setVideoPath("/sdcard/heman.mp4");
    reprod2.start();

    reprod2.setKeepScreenOn(true);

    if (reprod2.canSeekForward())
        reprod2.seekTo(reprod2.getDuration()/2);


    //hacer algo durante la reproducción

    //reprod2.stopPlayback();

    salir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VideoActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Im not an android dev so I can't help, but you might have better luck getting a response if you edit your question to include some of your code and/or error messages. Try including the code where you attempt to pass the file path.

Comment: I edited and added the code ;)